# stackplot in matplotlib 1.4

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

The demo `stackplot` code fails for me since upgrading to matplotlib 1.4.0  It works with 1.2.1
http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/stackplot_demo.html

The error is `AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'stackplot'` and indeed I don't see that method anymore.

I'm using Mac OS 10.9.5 and python 2.7.5